# NoFlo - how to start a graph / network

Tags: noflo

Pure Data has a `loadbang` component, which does what it says: sends one bang when the graph starts running. NoFlo's `core/Kick` doesn't send its data until its `IN` input is hit, and you can't save a bang IIP in noflo-ui.

Answer (score 2):

`core/Repeat` with an IIP (any string) on the `IN` port will do what you're looking for. Here is a browser example that shows a popup alert when the network starts:

```
loadbang(core/Repeat) OUT -> IN alert(core/MakeFunction)
'alert("hi");' -> FUNCTION alert
':-)' -> IN loadbang
```

[image: noflo-ui rendering of above graph]

Related discussion: https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui/issues/97

Comment: Keep the order of IIPs in mind, as that will change how the graph runs. See: https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui/issues/111

Comment: http://flowhub.io/documentation/getting-started-browser/ is good to answer the general question of: "how do I get started with flowhub?"  I point this out, as this seems to be the only question/answer on SO that even speaks to how I create the equivalent "Hello World" app.